# Alexander Polynomial

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, knot-theory, geometric-group-theory, knot-invariants

Recently I learned the Alexander Polynomial of a knot and how to find the polynomial for a given knot. Now there are some questions arise,
I am trying to give some classification of hyperbolic knots, basically, I want to classify the hyperbolic knot groups, for the knots in $S^3$. Also, I want to find finite index subgroups of hyperbolic knot groups, which is why I have the following questions.

1. For a given Alexander Polynomial can we classify all the knots?
2. Suppose I want to find all knots whose Alexander Polynomial polynomial is = 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question 2 came up on MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410237/infinite-family-of-different-prime-knots-with-trivial-alexander-polynomial Also of possible interest, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185486/can-infinitely-many-alternating-knots-have-the-same-alexander-polynomial

Comment: And Stavros Garoufalidis & Peter Teichner, On Knots With Trivial Alexander
Polynomial, J. Differential Geometry 67 (2004) 165-191, available at https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Math/ewExternalFiles/Alexander.pdf

Comment: Any interest in those references, T ghosh?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the sharing the links, I have looked at the link you have mentioned it really helped me it's very interesting. Precisely I am trying to studying the Cayley Graphs of the knot groups, trying to figure out which knot groups are hyperbolic.

Comment: Maybe those links have given you enough information to post at least a partial answer to your question?

Comment: Yeah, I have just quickly go through this paper. Still I am thiking. Definitely it gave some partial answers, it's a very helpful.